# Can't Figure Out How To Join Elements In 2D Array

Tags: javascript

I tried to figure this out multiple ways but it looks like my Javascript abilities are not quite there yet. I have a 2D array that includes some true and false elements. The idea is to join the last 4 elements of each array within the 2D array into a string, but removing any false values:

Original Array

```
var data = [
  ['apple', false, 1, false, 2, 5],
  ['orange',true,  2, 5, false, 2],
  ['pear',true, 3, 7, false, false]
  ];
```

Desired result:

```
var data = [
  ['apple', false, "1, 2, 5"],
  ['orange',true,  "2, 5, 2"],
  ['pear',true, "3, 7"]
  ];
```

Any ideas how I can go about this?

Comment: Can you please add the code that shows what you already tried yourself?

Comment: I pretty much tried to map it out and run some filter functions on the individual elements, but that was not working so I deleted it lol. However next time I will include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [joining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const data = [
  ['apple', false, 1, false, 2, 5],
  ['orange', true,  2, 5, false, 2],
  ['pear', true, 3, 7, false, false]
];

const result = data.map(([ fruit, flag, ...rest ]) => [
  fruit,
  flag,
  rest.filter(v => v !== false).join(', ')
]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I understand the map method but I will need to study three dot notation and the flag variable.

Comment: Kind of... that makes sense now that you showed the answer above, but what I was trying to do something like x[3].filter(Boolean) and that was not working.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if your data has length more than the fixed one(for ex. 6).

```js
var data = [['apple', false, 1, false, 2, 5],['orange',true,  2, 5, false, 2],['pear',true, 3, 7, false, false]];
  
console.log(data.map(o=>[...o.slice(0,-4), o.slice(-4).filter(Boolean).join(",")]));
```